# Prove the inequality $\sum_{cyc} \frac{a}{1+b^2} \ge \frac{6}{5}$ with $a+b+c=\frac{3}{2}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Given that $a+b+c=\frac{3}{2}$, prove that $$\sum_{cyc} \frac{a}{1+b^2} \ge \frac{6}{5}$$

The inequality seems quite strong, I couldn't prove it using CS, Muirhead, AM-GM, etc.

I wouldn't be surprised if homogenising and a brute force technique (uvw, Muirhead, etc. or Langrange from the get-go) worked but I'm intrigued if there's a clever (and why not short) solution.

Comment: No effort shown here. You should know by now that questions such as these go against the MSE Guidelines. -1 and Vote-To-Close.

Comment: I honestly fail to understand why listing all my failed attempts (or just trying to write one in length) would actually add any value to this. But I've done it regardless so the *MSE* moderators are happy! It was an old problem I tried to solve and just stumbled across it again. I guess I have to add filler text hoping to waste someone's time.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite variables:
$\sum_{cyc} \frac{x}{1+y^2} \ge \frac{6}{5}$ with $x+y+z = \frac{3}{2}$.

Now let $a = 2 x$ etc., then equivalently
$\sum_{cyc} \frac{a}{4+b^2} \ge \frac{3}{5}$ with $a+b+c = 3$.

The solution of this can be found [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2533838p21550080).